# Need to show hide div on click of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating forum related to medical help. In which there will many questions asked by patients, which will be answered by doctors. I have shown the question and and its details on one page:

```
select * from queries
```

using above query. Where all the questions are see with its title and some description.

There will be many question, just consider one question answered, which has 4 replies. I have the code ready for that as well as below

```
$viewDet = "select * from queries where queryCode = '". $qryId."'";
```

thus the user will see question with 4 replies. Each of the reply will be shown proper with a block containing following code

```
<td width="166" height="69" align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC">Rate This Question </td>
    <td width="136" align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC; background-image:
            url(images/medalsgold1.png);background-position:center; background-repeat:no-repeat">
            <a href="#" > <span class="style1 style2">Gold</span> </a>
    </td>

    <td width="140" align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC; background-image:
            url(images/medalssilver1.png); background-position:center; background-repeat:no-repeat">
            <a href="#" ><span class="style1 style2"> Silver </span></a>
    </td>
    <td width="138" align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC; background-image:
            url(images/medalbronze1.png); background-position:center; background-repeat:no-repeat">
            <a href="delete" ><span class="style1 style2">Bronze </span></a>
    </td>

    </div>

    <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" style="background-image:url(images/availabilityBg1.png);  background-position:center; background-repeat:no-repeat    
        ; color:#FFFFFF; border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC ">
        <a id="<?php echo $row['queryID'];  ?>" class="customLnk" href="#"> 
            Ask Follow Up Question            </a>        </td>
```

thus after clicking the Ask Follow Up Question the user should get a popup just below that link.

How can I achieve this? As every reply is dynamic I don't know how to assign the id to the particular link and show the form attached to that link. 
I don't have reputation so I can't upload image so it is difficult to explain.

Comment: `I am creating forum related to medical help`

why reinvent the wheel, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software The popular ones will have plugins (/mods) that will allow thread ratings

Comment: #Kedar if my answer solved your problem could you up vote it and set it as the correct answer so that this question shows as being solved.

Answer (score 0):

on a click event you can just set the `div` `display:none` to `display:block`

```
document.getElementById("myclickableElement").addEventListener("click",function(){
   document.getElementById("BoxToShowID").style.display="block";
},false);
```

you can use this simple example to traverse multiple elements that you want to show/hide based on any event trigger.

In a JavaScript file that is linked to the page you can add this snippet into the file. change `myclickableElement` with the id of the element you want to receive the click event. change `BoxToShowID` to the id of the element you want to have react when the click event happens. You will see the section `.style.display="block";` you can change this up to change any css styling.

```
document.getElementById("myclickableElement")//this gets the element by its ID
element.addEventListener(eventType,functionToCall,TraversEventUpTree)//this adds the event to the element.
element.style.display="block";//set style display of element to block.
```

Do not put any onclick actions in your html. you will not be changing anything in your html file.

Comment: thanks for answer...where i should put the above code. please explain a little bit more plz...Do i have put onclick and call a function containing above code..i will be thanks full if u reply this query.

Comment: I just added more details. please note that you simply need to change the id's to what ever id's you need. Its only two IDs and you should have your JavaScript in a *.js file and include all your javascript files in the header. don't put javascript in your HTML put javascript in a javascript file.